# Promela: how to use a for loop for an array of type typedef

Tags: spin, promela

I would like to be able use a for loop to loop through an array of typedef values as demonstrated below:

```
typedef chanArray {
    chan ch[5] = [1] of {bit};
}
chanArray comms[5];

active proctype Reliable() {
    chanArray channel;
    for ( channel in comms ) {
        channel.ch[0] ! 0;
    }   
}
```

Spin gives the following error:

```
spin: test2.pml:8, Error: for ( channel in .channel_name ) { ... }
```

Is it possible to use a for loop in this form to loop through the array instead of having to use a for loop with an index pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
active proctype Reliable () {
  byte index;

  index = 0;
  do
  :: index < 5 -> channel.ch[index] ! 0; index++
  :: else -> break
  od
}
```

this is the only way.  So the answer to your 'is it possible ...' question is 'no, it is not possible ...'

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Promela, but it seems that you are using

```
for '(' varref in channel ')' '{' sequence '}'
```

instead of

```
for '(' varref ':' expr '..' expr ')' '{' sequence '}'
```

Try with something like

```
int i;
for (i : 0..4 ) {...}
```